# Having Flutter gorouter redirect property doesn't let navigation work

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-go-router

Having Flutter gorouter redirect property at top-level doesn't let navigation to go to/push any other page. It redirects to initialLocation upon pressing routing button instead of intended page(ItemOne()).

**Log:**

```
[GoRouter] going to /one
[GoRouter] redirecting to RouteMatchList(/)
```

**Gorouter Code:**

```
void main() => runApp(const NavApp());

const isAuth = true;

class NavApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const NavApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      routerConfig: GoRouter(
        debugLogDiagnostics: true,
        initialLocation: '/',
        redirect: (context, state) => isAuth ? '/' : '/one',
        routes: [
          GoRoute(
            path: '/',
            builder: (context, state) => const NavHome(),
          ),
          GoRoute(
            path: '/one',
            builder: (context, state) => const ItemOne(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**HomePage Code:**

```
class NavHome extends StatelessWidget {
  const NavHome({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Nav Home'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: IconButton(
          onPressed: () => context.push('/one'),
          icon: const Text('Push One'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Page we route to using button:**

```
class ItemOne extends StatelessWidget {
  const ItemOne({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Item 1'),
      ),
      body: const Text('This is page for Item One'),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
redirect: (context, state) => isAuth ? null : '/one',
```

Try to replace the `'/'` with null.

Answer (score 0):

Please use it like this

```
Center(
    child: IconButton(
       onPressed: () => context.go('/one'),
      icon: const Text('Push One'),
    ),
```

Comment: Whether I use go or push, doesn't matter. It is still not working.

Comment: I checked the code myself. It was the condition you gave with "redirect" that caused the problem. If you did this condition with the intention of making it the start page when you log in, this is an error. If you want to redirect the user to "/one" after logging in, do so in "initialLocation".


example: https://gist.github.com/AlakbarHeyderov/7d2c0defd4df8655e059c38906c20a2f